# error installing rosserial arduino

Tags: ros, arduino, std-msgs, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i'm following the     rosserial_arduino/    Tutorials/    Arduino IDE Setup

I run the first line : hg clone https://kforge.ros.org/rosserial/hg rosserial , and it works well

but when i gonna run the second line about dependencies :  rosdep install rosserial_arduino
i obtained this ERROR:

ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
rosserial_arduino: Missing resource std_msgs
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/moni/fuerte_workspace
ROS path [2]=/home/moni/rosserial
ROS path [3]=/home/moni/rosserial/rosserial_arduino

i was trying to change de directory of ros path.. but i don't know why doesn't work.

Please Help! it's Urgent!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46832/error-installing-rosserial-arduino/) by [monidiaz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3475/monidiaz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2012-10-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can you install rosserial directly from the package repositories?

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-rosserial
```

---

Originally posted by [Jon Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2281/jon-stephan/) with karma: 837 on 2012-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was having similar problems, but when I put the package under the row_workspace directory, I was able to build just fine.

---

Originally posted by [wegunterjr](https://answers.ros.org/users/3479/wegunterjr/) with karma: 41 on 2012-10-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1